# Django Postman Messaging

Tags: python, django

So i've got django-postman installed in my project. I've got the app installed and the urls are added but it's still not working.

When I try and send a message to the user *test* for example it's saying "Some usernames are unknown or no more active: test." which makes me think it's trying to use the wrong user model because the username exists in the database, it just can't find it.

I've got these in my settings if it helps.

```
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_ANONYMOUS = False
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_MULTIRECIPIENTS = False

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

Looking at the code for django-postman I have found out the issue. In [postman.future_1_5.py](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/src/95d5e1b67a3e643d0a699eba601e779b307d43f9/postman/future_1_5.py?at=default) it just imports User instead of what I need.

How can I change this code? Is there a way I can keep a file within my application and use that instead?

I'm thinking this will fix my issue:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from accounts.models import MyUser

MyUser.USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
MyUser.get_username = lambda self: self.username

def get_user_model():
    return MyUser
```

Comment: Have a look at [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842987/django-postman-not-working/65825202#65825202). May be this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying future_1_5.py is not the solution to your issue, and is a very bad idea anyway. As its name implies, this file is intended to make the code runnable with Django before version 1.5.

I suppose you're running at least Django 1.5, so if this fallback is fired it means that your custom user model could not be imported.

The right explanation is that your setting is wrong. It has to name the effective model:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
```

Comment: Yea I have that in my settings already, I don't understand why it is not finding any users