# Django-postman not working

Tags: python, django

I tried to implement `Django-postman` for the user to user messaging system.

I cloned the repo and did this in my `settings.py` and `URLs.py` file too:

In `URLs.py` of main file i have included :

```
 re_path(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman')),
```

In Settings.py file I have included:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'postman',
    'account',
    'landingpage',
]

POSTMAN_I18N_URLS = True  # default is False
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_ANONYMOUS = True  # default is False
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_MULTIRECIPIENTS = True  # default is False
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_COPIES_ON_REPLY = True  # default is False
POSTMAN_DISABLE_USER_EMAILING = True  # default is False
POSTMAN_FROM_EMAIL = 'from@host.tld'  # default is DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
#POSTMAN_PARAMS_EMAIL = get_params_email  # default is None
POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True  # default is None
POSTMAN_SHOW_USER_AS = 'get_full_name'  # default is None
POSTMAN_NAME_USER_AS = 'last_name'  # default is None
POSTMAN_QUICKREPLY_QUOTE_BODY = True  # default is False
POSTMAN_NOTIFIER_APP = None  # default is 'notification'
POSTMAN_MAILER_APP = None  # default is 'mailer'
```

URLs of postman:

```
urlpatterns = [
        # Translators: keep consistency of the <option> parameter with the translation for 'm'
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^inbox/(?:(?P<option>m)/)?$'), InboxView.as_view(), name='inbox'),
        # Translators: keep consistency of the <option> parameter with the translation for 'm'
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^sent/(?:(?P<option>m)/)?$'), SentView.as_view(), name='sent'),
        # Translators: keep consistency of the <option> parameter with the translation for 'm'
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^archives/(?:(?P<option>m)/)?$'), ArchivesView.as_view(), name='archives'),
        # Translators: keep consistency of the <option> parameter with the translation for 'm'
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^trash/(?:(?P<option>m)/)?$'), TrashView.as_view(), name='trash'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^write/(?:(?P<recipients>[^/#]+)/)?$'), WriteView.as_view(), name='write'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^reply/(?P<message_id>[\d]+)/$'), ReplyView.as_view(), name='reply'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^view/(?P<message_id>[\d]+)/$'), MessageView.as_view(), name='view'),
        # Translators: 't' stands for 'thread'
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^view/t/(?P<thread_id>[\d]+)/$'), ConversationView.as_view(), name='view_conversation'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^archive/$'), ArchiveView.as_view(), name='archive'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^delete/$'), DeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^undelete/$'), UndeleteView.as_view(), name='undelete'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^mark-read/$'), MarkReadView.as_view(), name='mark-read'),
        url(pgettext_lazy('postman_url', r'^mark-unread/$'), MarkUnreadView.as_view(), name='mark-unread'),
        url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('postman:inbox'), permanent=True)),
    ]
```

Write.html

```
{% extends "postman/base_write.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block pm_write_title %}{% trans "Write"%}{% endblock %}
```

base_write.html

```
{% extends "postman/base.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
{% if autocompleter_app.is_active %}{# using the available admin jQuery is enough #}
{# should not be necessary since AS v1.3 with AJAX_SELECT_BOOTSTRAP set #}
{#<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>#}
{% endif %}
{{ form.media }}{# for ajax_selects (v1.3.6 at least) #}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div id="postman">
<h1>{% block pm_write_title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
<form action="{% if next_url %}?next={{ next_url|urlencode }}{% endif %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{% block pm_write_recipient %}{% endblock %}
{{ form.as_table }}
</table>
<button type="submit" class="pm_btn pm_btn-send">{% trans "Send" %}</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Base.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}{# not myself but a site-level one (TEMPLATE_DIRS setting) #}
{% load i18n static %}{% load postman_tags %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Messaging" %}{% endblock %}
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'postman/css/postman.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}
{% block postman_menu %}
<ul id="postman_menu">{% postman_unread as unread_count %}
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:inbox' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Inbox" %}{% if unread_count %} <strong>({{ unread_count }})</strong>{% endif %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:sent' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Sent Messages" %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:write' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Write" %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:archives' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Archives" %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url 'postman:trash' %}">&raquo;&nbsp;{% trans "Trash" %}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that whenever I run 127.0.0.1:8000/messages/write in my browser, the website is blank.
The django admin shows messaging boxes but the url returns blank. What am i doing wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Below are the steps that will get you started with bare-minimum:

1. On the root directory (directory with `manage.py`)
   `python3 -m pip install django-postman`
2. In `settings.py` :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    ...,
    # 'pagination'  # has to be before postman
    # ...
    'postman',
    # ...
    # 'ajax_select'
    # 'notification'
    # 'mailer'
]
    
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        '...,
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/ 'templates'],
        ...
    },
]
```

3. On the root directory execute the following command:
   `python manage.py migrate`

   `mkdir -p templates/postman`

`touch templates/postman/base.html`

Now you should be able to see the `Messages` and `Pending` on the admin page of your site.

4. Add the following markup to the `base.html` file we created in the above step:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            {% block title %}
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        {% block extrahead %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        
        {% block postman_menu %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This is because the package expects this template to be able to render the urls.
5. Add this path path to the project's urlpatterns:

```
path('messages/', include('postman.urls'), name='postman'),
```

6. Now you can use any of the urls on the actual site

   `localhost:8000/messages/write`

There is one catch, by default the messages that you send will be ***pending*** so either you have to approve from the admin site ( by moderator) manually or you can set the
`POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS=True` in the `settings.py.`

Most of the above have been mentioned in [django-postman documentation](https://django-postman.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#examples), but it was very challenging for me as a beginner to grasp these, So I have tried to simplify the steps, Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: thanks. it's weird that the documentation doesn't really tell you that pip install is possible, instead it tells you to download the tool manually.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the required template blocks in YOUR base.html template that the postman/base.html is extending?

From: https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/wiki/quickstart#rst-header-templates

> The `postman/base.html` template extends a `base.html` site template, in which some blocks are expected: 
> •title: in `<html><head><title>`, at
>   least for a part of the entire title string 
>   
> •extrahead: in
>   `<html><head>`, to put some `<script>` and `<link>` elements 
>   
> •content: in
>   `<html><body>`, to put the page contents 
>   
> •postman_menu: in `<html><body>`,
>   to put a navigation menu

Answer (score 0):

Second the answer from *@Amiay Narayan*, with some modifications on the base.html file part.

The latest base.html from the Django-postman is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}{# not myself but a site-level one (TEMPLATE_DIRS setting) #}
```

So in the base.html of your own Django project, the only thing that needs to be added somewhere between the <body>.....</body> is Django-postman's simple menu:

```
    {% block postman_menu %}
    {% endblock %}
```